# What policies are in place to help mitigate the downsides of capitalism?

Tags: economy

There are pros and cons to all economic models and in order to help reduce the downsides of the US capitalistic economy policies have been put into place for that purpose.  For example, the minimum wage helps prevent 'slave wages' by businesses whose employees require only minimal skill sets and thus a glut of employment opportunities, i.e. fast food.

Is there a well known list of the cons of capitalism and the policies which help reduce the impact of those 'cons'?

Comment: minimum wage was traditionally used as protection for unions/working men from women and children being employed. Its only recently that people have been working to revise their history to preventing slave wages and exploitation.

Comment: Here's a decent comparison of minimum wage and EITC. http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/3179/under-what-criteria-is-a-minimum-wage-law-superior-to-an-earned-income-tax-credi

Comment: Ryanthal, I am not interested in history, revisionist or otherwise.  I think my example says that minimum wage can help prevent slave wages or 'wage inequality' which, I believe, is a natural negative component of unregulated capitalism.  Is that inaccurate?

Comment: @TracyCramer - no. There's no concept of "slave wages". If someone performs a job worth $1, you pay them $1. If you perform a job worth more than $1, you can go work for someone else offering $1.01 who will make a profit off of stealing your productivity from the current employer. Short of active collusion (agreement to hold wages down between competitors), that's not slavery.

Comment: @TracyCramer - the only "slavery" is in forcing someone against their will to pay money to a person who wants your money and is unable to peacefully persuade you that they can provided you something worth that money in trade.

Comment: The policies are that of most any *regulated* capitalist market. Most capitalist markets *are* regulated.

Comment: @DVK I think it's fair to say that "slave wages" is a metaphorical phrase, not literal.

Comment: I think for the answers to be specific, we'd need to address specific 'cons' of capitalism, as what can be considered a con can vary wildly across point of views.

Comment: This might help: http://www.economicshelp.org/blog/5002/economics/pros-and-cons-of-capitalism/ of the cons listed there, there are typically public policies enacted to limit them.

Comment: This question is really too broad. What constitutes a con of capitalism and what regulation might be necessary to deal with it is a subject for a very long series of economics textbooks, not a stackexchange answer.

Comment: @DA., Avi is probably right here. This question should probably focus specifically on a particular outcome of capitalism that they wish was mitigated (perhaps **con** shouldn't be used. I.e. capitalism leads to greater inequality of outcome, which may be a good or bad thing depending upon your point of view)

Comment: I agree. Too broad as is.

Comment: @DA. - the link you provided helps list the cons very well.  I would be interesting to see some of the policies the US has in place to mitigate the items in the list.

Comment: @cramerTV I'd suggest updating your question to reflect that specific list of cons. I'd also ask if you are asking in general, or in the context of a particular nation. I'd still argue that 'economic policy', in general, is how all of that is managed.

Answer (score 3):

There's all sorts of policies:

- environmental protection laws
- workers rights laws
- occupational safety laws
- tax laws
- tax penalties
- tax incentives
- grants
- social programs
- banking laws
- trade agreements
- safety laws
- food and drug laws
- etc.

Most (all?) capitalist economies are regulated on some level--obviously some more than others.

Comment: I think you need to connect which downsides are mitigated by which of these regulations. And what the downside of capitalism is. What you have now is a list of things that interfere with the pros of capitalism and make of less effective.

Comment: @user1873 I think the question needs to answer that rather than the answers...since it'd be highly opinion based--our interpretation of what constitutes a pro vs con clearly being different as an example.

Comment: @user1873 actually, come to think of it, I think the question is technically unanswerable until the OP defines what they feel as being cons. As the answers will be all over the board based on subjective opinions.

Comment: agreed. They need to define the cons specifically for us to answer what policies mitigate those issues. I assumed the OP was refering to things that lower the earning power of individuals (hence my answer), but it could be that the OP was interested in **cons** that detract from business investment/profits in the country.

Comment: @user1873 well, that's a good example, actually, you may feel immigration hurts that, I may feel monopolies hurt that. Both are valid. Both have policies enacted to help remedy it. In the end, one could argue that all economic policies are a way to regulate against the cons of any particular economic model.

Comment: Not really a good answer, but can't be improved that I can see due to really poor question.

Answer (score -2):

Their are some things that mitigate the cons of Capitalism, but nothing has been [more effective](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9836/do-the-rich-get-richer-and-the-poor-get-poorer) at raising more people [out of poverty](http://www.economist.com/news/leaders/21578665-nearly-1-billion-people-have-been-taken-out-extreme-poverty-20-years-world-should-aim) than it.

**A strong immigration policy that limits the numbers of skilled worker immigrants and heavily punishes illegal immigration.**

Immigration tends to lower wages, becuase a [larger supply](http://www.npr.org/blogs/thetwo-way/2011/12/01/143021394/pew-63-percent-of-undocumented-immigrants-in-u-s-for-more-than-10-years) of workers. This is especially true in [low skilled jobs](http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=5250150) that would traditionally be performed by teenagers with little work experience. Even higher [skilled professions](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/crux/2012/06/13/no-america-does-not-need-more-scientists-and-engineers/) have seen reduced wages because of the availability of H1B visas.

The punishment for hiring an illegal immigrant is [fairly low](http://www.legalmatch.com/law-library/article/penalties-for-employers-hiring-illegal-immigrants.html) ($250-$2,000). Their may also be no fine at all if the illegal immigrant steals someone's identity. If the employer makes a "Good Faith Effort" to verify that the name they were given matches the name in the SSA database. A [stronger way](http://cis.org/IRSTaxID-ImmigrationLaw) of identifying who is eligible to work would help reduce wage deflation.

**Lowering or removing tarriffs on imported/exported goods**

Tarriffs lower the [purchasing power](http://economics.about.com/cs/taxpolicy/a/tariffs_2.htm) of the people who work in the nations that impose them. [NAFTA](http://www.ustr.gov/trade-agreements/free-trade-agreements/north-american-free-trade-agreement-nafta), for example, reduced the cost of importing goods into/out of the USA.

**Limiting government regulations.**

Government regulations can be used to stymie [competition](http://reason.com/blog/2014/02/04/federal-court-invalidates-kentucky-law-a) in a market. It also causes a drag on [productivity](http://www.aei-ideas.org/2014/05/heres-how-crony-capitalism-and-regulation-kill-us-economic-growth/#mbl).

> A comparison of the RegData data to production-efficiency measures provided shows that industries that are subject to less regulation have significantly higher production-efficiency measures than do industries that are subject to more regulation.

Comment: Immigration also increases the demand for goods and services, which would drive up wages and create opportunities for entrepreneurship. Do you have any evidence to suggest why the decrease in wages due to an increase in the supply of labor would necessarily outpace the increase in demand in the labor market. Beyond that, even if wages do go down, do you have any evidence to suggest that the decrease in labor costs wouldn't translate through competition into lower prices for goods and services making everyone better off?

Comment: I'm not sure I see a 'con' of capitalism being addressed in your answer.  If I've missed it please add a comment to help me understand.

Comment: @lazarusL, is that directed at me, or the OP who states that minimum wage is a policy that reduces the downsides of capitalism? Wouldn't not having a minimum wage also translate to completion and lower prices for goods and services, making everyone better off?

Comment: @user1873 it was directed at you. You made a bunch of claims that didn't seem obvious and none of your sources seemed to deal with the issues that I think would have to be the crux of such an economic analysis. I took the use of the minimum wage in the question as an example of a policy people might think would deal with a potential flaw in capitalism, not an assertion that the minimum wage is an effective policy.

Comment: @lazarusL, the claims I made are issues that can be used to mitigate the downsides of capitalistic economic policy. Government regulations for example can be used to block competition, in one way by making the **cost of implementing those regulations very expensive**. I believe Congress passed a law requiring that all new regulations be **cost neutral**. Would a link to that law be sufficient?

Comment: @user1873 My questions/commnet were only in reference to your immigration claims.

Comment: @lazarusL, "*Do you have any evidence to suggest why the decrease in wages due to an increase in the supply of labor would necessarily outpace the increase in demand in the labor market.*" I am not sure why I would have to. A completely free labor market would decrease wages because of an increase in supply (I assume people would consider this a downside). Why would that cause an increase in demand? Wouldn't wages have to increase **by more** if their wasn't such a large supply of people willing to work for the lower wages? Ask all the roofers, carpenters, plumbers, if the booming housing mark

Comment: Market was able to keep their wages up with the influx of illegal alien workers.

Comment: @user1873 so we are looking at the effect of more people entering the country. This indisputably causes an increase in the supply of workers as you suggested. These new people, in addition to supplying goods and services, also demand them. They will purchase houses, demanding more construction firms. They will eat food, demanding more restaurants. Entrepreneurial immigrants will found various businesses, increasing the demand for workers (http://tinyurl.com/oxftkjv). These shifts in demand for workers could potentially outpace the shift in supply of workers and at least need to be addressed.

Comment: @lazarusL, so you are contending that illegal immigration is actually a benefit of capitalism. Perhaps we should just have completely open boarders and allow everyone to come into the USA. Why didn't we just do that to [stimulate the economy and reduce unemployment](http://www.dallasnews.com/business/columnists/mitchell-schnurman/20130105-more-immigrants-more-economic-stimulus.ece)?

Comment: @user1873 I'm not contending anything, your comment asserted that immigration was a bad thing and I questioned what evidence led you to that conclusion. There are certainly a large number of people who study the subject that would be in favor of more immigration than we have now http://www.npr.org/blogs/money/2013/02/21/172501563/three-ways-to-totally-transform-u-s-immigration-policy
http://www.cato.org/publications/free-trade-bulletin/immigrants-move-americans-move

Comment: @lazarusL, at this point though, it doesn't matter, "This indisputably causes an increase in the supply of workers as you suggested." If someone wants to prove that, "these shifts in demand for workers **could potentially** outpace the shift in supply of workers," That's their choice, but without evidence otherwise my point stands.

Comment: @user 1873 We've identified 2 effects. You provided no reasoning or evudence to suggest that one would be greater in magnitude than the other. So based on the information in this thread I am still left wondering whether immigration is a force of capitalism which must be limited or a perk which should be allowed.

Comment: @lazarusL, ok, so you agree that a large supply of new immigrant workers (illegal or otherwise) would lower wages (evident in links above). For the remaining part, "Beyond that, even if wages do go down, do you have any evidence to suggest that the decrease in labor costs wouldn't translate through competition **into lower prices for goods and services** making everyone better off?" **Would you accept the fact that inflation has reduced the purchasing power of people with lower wages?** (And accept as evidence the change in the CPI over the last 5-10 years?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15967/discussion-between-lazarusl-and-user1873).

Comment: This seems to be an answer for the question "what policies interfere (arguably) with the pros of capitalism"